# BST removing node with 2 children not deleting predecessor

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am working on removing nodes from a BST. It currently works for all cases in which there is no children, or one child. When I go to remove a node with 2 children, the node gets removed, but the predecessor value does not get changed to null as I feel the code accounts for that, but nothing changes.

```
   public Node(String w, Node p, Node l, Node r) {
         //value = v;
         word = w;
         parent = p;
         left = l;
         right = r;
      }
   public void remove(String target) {
      if (root == null) {
         return;
      }
      if (root.word.compareTo(target) == 0)
      {
         removeRoot(target);
      }
      else {
         removeNonRoot(target);
      }
   }
   private void removeNonRoot(String target) {

      Node cur = root;
      Node parent = null;

      while (cur != null) {
         if (cur.word.compareTo(target) == 0) {
            break;
         }
         if (target.compareTo(cur.word) < 0) {
            if (cur.left != null) {
               parent = cur;
               cur = cur.left;
            }
         }
         else if (target.compareTo(cur.word) > 0) {
            if (cur.right != null) {
               parent = cur;
               cur = cur.right;
            }
         }
      }
     if (cur.left == null && cur.right == null)
      {
         if (parent.left != null && parent.left.word.compareTo(target) == 0) {
            parent.left = null;
         }
         else if (parent.right != null && parent.right.word.compareTo(target) == 0)
         {  
            parent.right = null;
         }
      }
      else if (cur.left == null && cur.right != null) {
         if (parent.right != null && parent.right.word.compareTo(target) == 0) {
            parent.right = cur.right;
         }
         else if (parent.left != null && parent.left.word.compareTo(target) == 0) {
            parent.left = cur.right;
         }
      }
      else {
         Node temp = findPredecessor(target, parent);
         cur.word = temp.word;
      }
   }
private void removeRoot(String target) {
   // only root
      if (root.left == null && root.right == null)
      {
         root = null;
         return;
      }
      // right child
      else if (root.left == null)
      {
         root = root.right;
         return;
      }
      // left child
      else if (root.right == null)
      {
         root = root.left;
      }
      // 2 children
      else
      {
         Node temp = findPredecessor(target, root);
         root.word = temp.word;
         return;
      }
   }

private Node findPredecessor(String s, Node start) {
      Node parent = start;
      Node child = start.left;

      if (child == null) {
         return parent;
      }
      else if (child != null) {
         while (child.right != null) {
            child = child.right;
         }
         Node temp = child;
         child.right = null;
         return temp;
      }
      else {
         return null;
      }
}
```

If I had a bst with characters inserted in this order: e -> f -> c -> a -> d the result from trying to remove c would return d where c was, but also the right subtree of d, would be d.

Which would lead me to believe the issue is in my predecessor method where I call child.right = null. I don't think the value actually get's assigned, but am unsure why.
Drawing of removal result:
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the post to make it [mre]. Include  hard coded test data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came down to adding 2 lines of code. Within removeNonRoot as the last line of the else block

```
cur.right = null;
```

and then within the removeRoot in the last else if block

```
removeNonRoot(temp.word);
```

And that made the difference in both instances for if there was 2 children to a root node and 2 children to a parent node with root not being null.

Answer (score 0):

It's little bit hard to follow the whole logic and what you are trying to achieve but, taking initial pass at your code I think the main problem is that you are not updating the parent information on your nodes.

**For Example:** When you are assigning the `cur.right` to `parent.right` or `parent.left`, you should also update the `parent` on `parent.right` to reflect the parent node correctly.

```java
else if (cur.left == null && cur.right != null) {
   if (parent.right != null && parent.right.word.compareTo(target) == 0) {
      parent.right = cur.right;
   } else if (parent.left != null && parent.left.word.compareTo(target) == 0) {
      parent.left = cur.right;
   }
   // Update parent information of `cur.right`
   cur.right.parent = parent;
}
```

You should make sure to update all such instances in your logic so that all the child nodes reflect their parent nodes correctly.

Comment: I am trying to handle cases in which I have two children nodes and need to replace that node with the right child. It moves the right child up, and removes the parent, but does not get rid of the right child's value/node.